# Need to execute a method 2 hour later after sending response in flask restplus

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful, flask-restplus

In eCommerce application, my requirement is, after placing the order send a notification(execute a method) to the seller after two hours.

What is the best way to automatically execute the method after 2 hours.?

Answer (score 0):

You can use celery to run tasks after a certain delay.

You can read more about it here

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/userguide/calling.html#eta-and-countdown

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will now fix my code and see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

This will work for **python3**.

If you are familiar with asyncio you can use the event loop *call_later* function.

> [Event loop](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html)
>
> **loop.call_later(delay, callback, *args, context=None)**
>
> Schedule
>   callback to be called after the given delay number of seconds (can be
>   either an int or a float).
>
> An instance of asyncio.TimerHandle is returned which can be used to
>   cancel the callback.
>
> callback will be called exactly once. If two callbacks are scheduled
>   for exactly the same time, the order in which they are called is
>   undefined.
>
> The optional positional args will be passed to the callback when it is
>   called. If you want the callback to be called with keyword arguments
>   use functools.partial().
>
> An optional keyword-only context argument allows specifying a custom
>   contextvars.Context for the callback to run in. The current context is
>   used when no context is provided.
>
> Changed in version 3.7: The context keyword-only parameter was added.
>   See PEP 567 for more details.
>
> Changed in version 3.8: In Python 3.7 and earlier with the default
>   event loop implementation, the delay could not exceed one day. This
>   has been fixed in Python 3.8.

Example [(Source)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#display-the-current-date-with-call-later):

```
import asyncio
import datetime

def display_date(end_time, loop):
    print(datetime.datetime.now())
    if (loop.time() + 1.0) < end_time:
        loop.call_later(1, display_date, end_time, loop)
    else:
        loop.stop()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

# Schedule the first call to display_date()
end_time = loop.time() + 5.0
loop.call_soon(display_date, end_time, loop)

# Blocking call interrupted by loop.stop()
try:
    loop.run_forever()
finally:
    loop.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will now fix my code and see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

In my production code I prefer APScheduler over Celery because it provides lots of settings on running jobs with specific delay or at specific date (so you can just add `timedelta(hours=2)` to you `datetime.utcnow()`)

Take a look at it:
https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/